# Retaining cookies whist opening pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drupal, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to create a script of which will log into drupal, and then is able to access every page on the site.

The issue i'm having is when authenticating to the site... it doesn't seem to be able to retain cookies and use them for each request, so then drupal things I'm unauthorised.

`http = Net::HTTP.new('www.example.com', 443)

http.use_ssl = true path = '?q=front_page&destination=front_page'

resp, data = http.get(path, nil) cookie = resp.response['set-cookie']

data = '"name=jobbloggs&pass=securepassword&op=Log in&form_id=user_login'

headers = {   'Cookie' => cookie,

'Referer' => 'https://www.example.com/',

'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)

puts data`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it easier to use mechanize, which will manage cookies for you and has a more facile DSL for screen scraping and similar purposes.